# When creating a character above 1st level, can you give them the effects of spellcasting services?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-creation

Page 199 of the DMG explains how new characters can start with magic items, even those they choose to make themselves (with the assumption these items were created some time before the character became a PC)

But let's say a non-spellcaster wants to give themselves an extra point to an ability score. If they have 27,500 gp, they could start with a *Manual of Quickness of Action* and either use it immediately or possibly say they've used it already and begin with an inherent +1 bonus to Dexterity.

That book costs 27,500 gp. Using the formula on page 129 of the PHB, however, it would only cost 26,530 gp to have a 17th-level wizard cast *wish* on them as a service. For an 8th-level character (or a higher-level character with lots of other gear), that's the difference between getting the bonus, and not.

Can the character simply decide to begin with this effect present (or a different spell with a permanent duration, like *enlarge person*+*permanency*, since 9th-level wizards are easy to find in large cities)  and 26,530 gp less, or since the DMG only describes starting with magic items, must they spend 27,500 gp for the magic item?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the book does not provide specific rules concerning spellcasting services as part of starting equipment, this is the GM's decision. There are, however, some indications that can inform the decision:

Page 111 of the PHB says (about buying starting equipment):

> Note  that  buying  beginning  equipment  this  way  is  an  abstraction.  Your  character  doesn’t  walk  into  a  store  with  handfuls  of  gold  and  buy  every  item  one  by  one.  Rather,  these  items  may  have  come  the  character’s  way  as  gifts  from   family,   equipment   from   patrons,   gear   granted   during  military  service,  swag  gained  through  duplicity,  and so on.

Therefore, the first question to ask is, whether the character could have come by the spellcasting service during their backstory - considering their origin and the abundance of magic in the respective world, for example.

Page 112 says:

> If  you  want  to  buy  something  not  described  in  this  chapter,  the  general rule is that you can buy anything that costs as much as 3,000 gp.

AND

> The  DM  determines  what  is  and  is  not  available  depending   on   how   he   or   she   runs   the   world   and   where   the   characters are in it.

The spellcasting services are something to be bought (indicated by the price tag provided) and they are not described in the equipment chapter. Since the price exceeds 3000 gp, however, the GM **has to** decide (RAW!) if it can be purchased.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: Good points! One bit of clarification, though: Looking in the PHB, it seems to me that Goods and Services *are* in the equipment chapter (Chapter 7), just at the very end of it. So it's not "something not described in this chapter", though it also isn't exactly "items described in this chapter", so it seems like your answer checks out.